# how to show list from POST response using retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to show response POST from retrofit. I don't really know how because my response are array but with POST.

this is how my response looks like

```
    {
   "message":[
      "00",
      "Get Success"
   ],
   "result":{
      "listProgram":[
         {
            "banner":"",
            "area":"",
            "domainlembaga":"",
            "domainprogram":"",
            "donate":0
        {
       .
       .
       .
       ]
```

service

```
    interface Service {

    @POST("program/list")
fun getProgram(@Body body: Pair<String, Int>, pair: Pair<String, Int>): Call<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>>
```

data

```
data class BaseBersedekahResponse<T>(
    @SerializedName("message") val message: String?,
    @SerializedName("result") val result: T?
)

data class ListProgramBersedekahResponse(
    @SerializedName("listProgram") val listProgram: List<ProgramBersedekahResponse>?
)

data class ProgramBersedekahResponse(
    @SerializedName("banner") val banner: String?,
    @SerializedName("domainlembaga") val domainlembaga: String?,
    @SerializedName("domainprogram") val domainprogram: String?,
    @SerializedName("donate") val donatur: Int?
)
```

activity

```
val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASEURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

val apiService: Service = retrofit.create(Service::class.java)

val call: Call<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>> = apiService.getProgram(
            "limit" to 1,
            "group" to 4)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>, response: Response<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>>) {
            val getProgram: List<ProgramBersedekahResponse?>? = response.body().result.listProgram
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```

I actually planning it to show in RecyclerView, but I still don't know how to show it the response from POST. please help.

Comment: "message" is not String in your json but it is String in your data class?

Comment: oh I didn't realize that thank you. but what I want to show as a list is in the result then listProgram. do you know how?

Comment: You are having namin issues :)  ````Call<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>>```` what you should use in call.enqueue but you have ````Call<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>````. And then your body is ````BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>```` and you are trying to get body as ````List<ProgramBersedekahResponse?>?````

Comment: There is a big confusion in your signatures. All mixed up.

Comment: You have wrapped list with ListProgramBersedekahResponse already and there should not be List<...> in anywhere while parsing your body.

Comment: can you show me the right way to call array inside object and inside object and show the response with the right way? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signatures should match each other. You should make your signatures same as the signature in your interface.

For your request body:

```
data class BersedekahRequest(
   @SerializedName("limint") val limint: Int, 
   @SerializedName("group") val group: Int
)
```

then your interface:

```
@POST("program/list")
fun getProgram(@Body body: BersedekahRequest): Call<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>>
```

your rest service call:

```
val requestBody = BersedekahRequest(10,20) 
val call: Call<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>> = apiService.getProgram(requestBody)

call.enqueue(object : Callback<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>, response: Response<BaseBersedekahResponse<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>>) {
        val GetApps2: List<ProgramBersedekahResponse?>? = response.body().result.listProgram
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ListProgramBersedekahResponse>, t: Throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
})
```

And I think one more problem you have.
`fun getProgram(@Body body: ProgramBersedekahResponse?)` this @Body is the body you will send via POST request, not your response body. If you do not send anything inside post body, make it empty, or give the appropriate request body since it seems like it is your response object right now.

Comment: the response still error I don't know why

Comment: and I already add the body like you said. I already updated my code. do you know why the response still error?

Comment: To know that, you should provide me the error log, otherwise I cannot know what is happening. Please print the stack trace of the throwable inside onFailure

Comment: I think the error because I add pair in the body in service. this is the error ` No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)`. do you know how to add the body in the right way?

Comment: You should give your body as @Body body: YourRequestBodyDataClass as a single instance and then put your attributes inside the YourRequestBodyDataClass. If you tell me what does your request body expect as json I can help.

Comment: my request body is limint and group and both are Integer

Comment: if the toast shows failure. what do you think can be wrong?

Comment: is showing listview from POST response really can be achieve?

Comment: What is the failure? You need data for your listview, it does not matter where the data comes from.

Comment: there is no error or anything. it just failure. I tried to add click listener to make sure. and it just failure toast

Comment: You should print the throwable log. Make t.printStackTrace() and then see the error.

Comment: it says `Expected an int but was 3155761208 at line 1 column 15040 path $.result.listProgram[20].collected`. collected is one of the value in listProgram

Comment: Max value that int can hold is 2,147,483,648, so just make it long.

Comment: thank you so so much it success now. but I have a question, is now I can call the data with ProgramBersedekahResponse? because I want to show it as a listview

Comment: it's okay I already did make the listview. thank you for your help. really appreciate it!